# ERROR: 6 - No data received from server in infusionsoft iSDK while adding contact

Tags: php, infusionsoft

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/infusionsoft_api/iSDK/src/isdk.php';
class Infusion
{

       $app = new iSDK;
            if($app->cfgCon("infusionapi",$app_name, $api_key)) {
                $conDat = array(
                    'FirstName' => 'ss',
                    'LastName' => 'aa',
                    'Email' => 'sachin.patil@gmail.com',
                    'StreetAddress1' => '11'
                );

                $conId = $app->addCon("Contact", $conDat);
                echo "sss".$conId;
                exit;
            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have posted some code and an error message, but you have not explained what you are trying  to do, and what is the question you want answered. If you could explain a little more you may get some help and assistance. I also note you have included an email address in the code. This is perhaps a little foolish in such a public internet forum.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin, are you checking to see if an error was generated? If an error is being thrown, you won't get back any return data but the error will be waiting for review in the result faultString() and result faultCode()

Comment: No, i am not checking to see if an error. i am just adding contact to infusionsoft but it gives this error. ERROR: 6 - No data received from server. what can i do now?

Comment: Sachin, are you sure that you're connecting to Infusionsoft first? You'll want to check for errors at all times, too, as if you weren't able to successfully connect to Infusionsoft, none of your calls will work.

Comment: i have connect infusionsoft successfully.  the problem is in iSDK file methodCaller function.  in this methodCaller i call send function client object. like it =  $this->client->send($call); this place it gives above error.